# Manage tiny fonts visualization with CSS/Javascript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am trying to create a website in which the navigation is based on zoomable contents.

For instance, here is a screenshot of what you can see just after opening the webpage:

[image: Small font]

Then, I am using [zoom.js](https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js) for "zooming" the page and be able to read the text. However, after the magnification I got this:

[image: Zoomeed font]

The font-size is set to 9.4%, and as you can see it causes characters to be overlapped and not correctly positioned.

I tried to use some jQuery plugin like [FitText.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) or [jQuery TextFill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill), just to see if they changed the font-size in some "magic" way that solve this issue; unfortunately they had effect in solving this visualization issue.

So my question is: how can I make the font looking "normal"? Is there any jQuery plugin or other JS library to manage this problem?

I am using Firefox, and I prefer to focus on using just this browser for the moment.

Comment: Did you try to just place the element regularly and set a: `transform: scale(0.05);` with css on it? this will make the element and it's content to be "scaled" to 5% of it's original size.

Comment: @NicoO I was going to suggest the same: Instead of starting off with a tiny font and expanding it, start off with a normal font that's shrunk, and then un-shrink.

Comment: @Nico, thanks for your suggestion, this is what I am trying to do now. However now the problem is with zoom.js, that is not writtent to consider a starting transformation applied to the whole page... Anyway, a solution that fix font and overlapping letters issues sould be better

Comment: Did you try to just kick `zoom.js` out? Basically you should be good with some css and some javascript event listeners that removes and add classes describing the zoom. Here is a plain css playground for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdmBBX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Nico O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3244925/nico-o) and [Ed Plunkett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett) in the comments, the solution to my problem was to start with a very big page, in which everything is 20 times bigger than the desired page size. Then I added the following CSS to scale everything 20 times smaller:

```
body {
    transform: scale(0.05);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

When I need to zoom on a point, I simply add new transformation parameters in the CSS, by changing the `transform` property (I used jQuery, but it can be done in many other ways):

```
$("body").css("transform", "scale("+scale_factor+") translate("+translate_data+")");
```

Note also that I didn't need any additional library (with the exception of jQuery) to do this.